# append the min max value lableof solidguage with string in highchart

Tags: highcharts

how to append the min max value lableof solidguage with string and some dynamic value in highchart  ?
I have used highchart for this

i tried below code but it shows min/max values as 0 with appended text

```
$(function () {

    var gaugeOptions = {

        chart: {
            type: 'solidgauge'
        },

        title: null,

        pane: {
            center: ['50%', '85%'],
            size: '140%',
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 90,
            background: {
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
                innerRadius: '60%',
                outerRadius: '100%',
                shape: 'arc'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },

        // the value axis
        yAxis: {
            stops: [
                [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
                [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
                [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
            ],
            lineWidth: 0,
            minorTickInterval: null,
            tickAmount: 2,
            title: {
                y: -70
            },
            labels: {
                y: 16
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            solidgauge: {
                dataLabels: {
                    y: 5,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    useHTML: true
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // The speed gauge
    $('#container-speed').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 200,
            title: {
                text: 'Speed'
            }
        },

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Speed',
            data: [80],
            dataLabels: {
                format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                    ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
                       '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">km/h</span></div>'
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' km/h'
            }
        }]

    }));

    // The RPM gauge
    $('#container-rpm').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 5,
            title: {
                text: 'RPM'
            },
             labels: {
                format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                    ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'yellow') + '">{y:.0f}|days left and '+data.marks'needed'</span><br/>' +
                       '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">* 1000 / min</span></div>'
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'RPM',
            data: [1],
            dataLabels: {
                format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                    ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y:.1f}</span><br/>' +
                       '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">* 1000 / min</span></div>'
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' revolutions/min'
            }
        }]

    }));

    // Bring life to the dials
    setTimeout(function () {
        // Speed
        var chart = $('#container-speed').highcharts(),
            point,
            newVal,
            inc;

        if (chart) {
            point = chart.series[0].points[0];
            inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 100);
            newVal = point.y + inc;

            if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
                newVal = point.y - inc;
            }

            point.update(newVal);
        }

        // RPM
        chart = $('#container-rpm').highcharts();
        if (chart) {
            point = chart.series[0].points[0];
            inc = Math.random() - 0.5;
            newVal = point.y + inc;

            if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 5) {
                newVal = point.y - inc;
            }

            point.update(newVal);
        }
    }, 2000);


});
```

`

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're doing to try to make your label, so we don't have to read through 100 lines of code trying to figure out what does what?

Comment: Do you mean that ticks should be printed on min and max only ?

Comment: I mean i want to show min/max value with some text example if solid guage has min value 100 then i want to show it as 100| science 2 year ago

Answer (score 0):

I accessed the div element of high chart by using class selector in jQuery and manipulated it after highchart operation.
$(".classname").html("new div tag")